# emacs auto-fill-mode doesn't initialise

Tags: emacs, word-wrap

I want to enable line-wrapping without having to type 'M-x auto-fill-mode' everytime I start emacs. I've tried putting `(setq auto-fill-mode 1)` and `(auto-fill-mode 1)` in the .emacs file, but neither work. Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use emacs to code? In that case you probably wouldn't want `auto-fill-mode` to be enabled globally.

Comment: Actually I use it for latex, thinking back I probably should have put this question in superuser.com instead of stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a minor-mode so you need to enable it for the modes where you want it used. So, for example, if you want auto-fill-mode enabled in text mode, you need to add the following to your .emacs file:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook '(lambda ()
                             (auto-fill-mode 1)))
```

Comment: How do I get it to work for latex mode? I've tried this: `(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook '(lambda ()
                             (auto-fill-mode 1)))` but it doesn't work

Comment: @Eddy: if you use AUCTeX, try `'LaTeX-mode-hook`.

Answer (score 2):

auto-fill-mode is a minor mode so (setq auto-fill-mode 1) wont start it.

You can add a hook to start auto-fill-mode with the text-mode (with which it is normally used) or any other mode you normally use it with, by doing

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
```

Alternatively, if you want the auto-fill-mode on for all the files you edit. You can start it when any type of file is opened with:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("*" . auto-fill-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

But having it always on is irritating at times, so its better to bind the starting of the mode to a familiar key sequence

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c q") 'auto-fill-mode)
```